# Inner subquery need to check in the same group but not across all groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select GroupId,count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID)as [ChildAddedcurrent]  
from #temp1 
Where (MonthFlag = 0) and (ParticipantTypeName = 'child')  
and (GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in 
(Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID 
from #temp1 
Where (MonthFlag = 1) and (ParticipantTypeName = 'child'))) 
group by groupId
```

The inner select query checks across all the groupid's in the table but I want it to be checking in the for each corresponding group referenced in the outer select query.

Comment: What exactly is your question about that query?

Comment: If you can't be bothered to properly explain your problem, we can't be bothered to try and help.

Comment: Sorry about that. The inner select query checks the records across all the groups but in need to check in the corresponding group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add in the subquery a where clause to reference the principal query by its groupId in order to get the result you are seeking.

```
Select GroupId,count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID)as [ChildAddedcurrent]  
from #temp1 
Where (MonthFlag = 0) and (ParticipantTypeName = 'child')  
and (GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in 
(Select distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID 
from #temp1 t
Where (t.MonthFlag = 1) and (t.ParticipantTypeName = 'child') and t.GroupId = GroupId)) 
group by groupId
```